# How can I express a single item in a set that meets a certain condition?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, convention

For example, how would I show that a variable is equal to a single item in a set which meets a certain condition?

Is set builder notation the best way?

E.g. $b = \{a \in A | f(a) = 3 \}$

The reason I am introducing an equality is because in my desired use case I am writing up some research, and I want to save space when writing further expressions with the item that I am pulling out of the set (so I can just use $b$ in the place of $\{a \in A | f(a) = 3 \}$ for example).

I'm not sure about using set builder notation because I thought it might imply that $b$ is a set when it is intended to be a single item.

Or should I perhaps write it like a sentence?

E.g. $b = a \in A$ where $f(a) = 3$.

I'm really not sure. If there are multiple ways of doing this it would be good to know some of the conventions. But ultimately I would like to be able to express this as succinctly as possible.

Comment: Good point, I used a bad example. I will edit it.

Comment: If I understand the question, I've answered; but if there's a little extra context about where you're trying to use this it'd be helpful as far as knowing I've answered properly.

Comment: I think you let $b\in\{a\in A\mid f(a)=3\}$. This approach uses two variables, but only one is needed. It is equivalent, and more succinct, to let $a\in A$ such that $f(a)=3$. However you should first prove that such an element must exist. The most technical way is probably let $a\in f^{-1}(3)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just trying to introduce a term that stands in for an arbitrary element of $A$ that satisfies the condition, you'd just want to use something like "$a\in A$ where $f(a)=3$".

You definitely would not want to use set builder notation like the first example, as this would be the subset of $A$ of all those things that satisfy $f(a)=3$. And using $b$ in the second example just adds a second variable that you don't really use.

Comment: So I guess I used $b$ to imply that I might want to then do something with the element I pulled out of $A$. My use case is extremely specific and would take a while to explain so I thought just including the $b$ provides the adequate implication. I'll specify this in the question. But in any case, even if I do need to express an equality with $b$, would you still agree that the sentence-like notation is better?

Comment: I editted the question to explain a little more

Comment: Yes, I would still just use the sentence. And I assumed you were going to make further references to this element, but there's still no reason to introduce $b$ to do that; just make the further statements about $a$.

Comment: Ah hang on (sorry I'm thinking like a computer scientist). So essentially I'm already saying that $a$ is the thing inside $A$ such that $f(a)=3$. Ergo $b$ is redundant right? So if for example I wanted to reserve the name $a$ to show any item in $A$, I could instead write $a^\prime \in A$ where $f(a^\prime) = 3$ and then continue to make further statements about $a^\prime$. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yup, exactly. It would be different if you started with "let $b\in\{a\in A:\varphi(a)\}$", because in that context $a$ is bound, so referring to $a$ later would be iffy, but referring to $b$ is entirely clear; but if you skip the set builder notation that's not a concern.

Answer (score 0):

You can write $b = \{3\}$ for your example.

Comment: I used a bad example. I will edit it now.